# DNS subdomain levels

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain that needs to use second level subdomain. I am curious why when I have the `@` A record and the blank A record a second level subdomain does not resolve. For example `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com` is not resolving to the root domain records. In this example if I add `subdomain` A record then that second level domain resolves.

Thanks for any clarification.

EDIT: This is using register.com as the DNS provider.

Comment: This should actually work. You don't need to have an A resource record for `sub.example.com` for `sub2.sub.example.com` to work. Post your zone files.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you told us what DNS software you are running. Don' be stingy with details.

Comment: @John Gardeniers - I edited my answer, sorry did not think the provider was necessary. I am not running DNS myself using Register.com.

Comment: in that case if your are having issues you really should contact the provider's support staff first, as they are in a much better position to help you than we are.

Comment: Ok, so I am taking it that this is not normal behavior of DNS. Make an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

if your are having issues you really should contact the provider's support staff first, as they are in a much better position to help you than we are -- from @John Gardeniers